# What types of fields shall I use for Long and Object values in javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, h2

I'd like to store values of the table created using `javafx` in data base. Some of values are of the Long type and others are of the object type. For example: there are three tables: "Goods", "Prices" and "TypesOfPrices". in this case the first one has two columns: "id" and "name", the third one has two same columns and the second has 3 fields: "price", "type_of_price", "good". It means that the second table has references to two other tables. I have no need to store references in database as far as I can use their IDs. But from the GUI user needs to have ability to choose value of the "Good" or "TypeOfPrice" type. So the question is What field type shell I choose to have drop down list of records of the other table when the user adds a record. For this purpose the dialog is used.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, for manipulating data with JavaFX you should use [Property](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm). In this way you will be able to bind data to your interface. For example if you want to bind a String to your TextField :

```
StringProperty myStringProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();
myStringProperty.bind(textfield.textProperty());
```

For a object TypeOfPrice :

```
    ObjectProperty<TypeOfPrice> objectProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty();
    Combobox<TypeOfPrice> typeOfPriceList = ...
  objectProperty.bind(typeOfPriceList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
```

In my opinion you should manipulate only property in your controller to make the link between the view and your data.

The boring part come when you want to save these data in your database.

In my first experience, we used H2 + JPA + Hibernate.
We had the model split in two parts, the first model written with Property and the second model written with classical java type like int, String ... that was this second model which was annotated with JPA, and a link was made between these two model. 
It looked something like [this](https://gist.github.com/james-d/e485ac525c71e20bb453)

Now we changed everything cause hibernate was too slow for our needs, we now use JCR repository for persistence layer. with [Modeshape](http://modeshape.jboss.org/) and [jcromFX](http://blog.dooapp.com/2014/10/javafx-persistence-made-easy-with.html) (a fork of [Jcrom](https://github.com/Kobee1203/jcrom)) for mapping and it works fine, you should take a look at it for alternative to classic H2 DB.